# statsmodels 2 dimensional kernel regression

Tags: python, statsmodels

I have a dataframe with 3 columns `['X', 'Y', 'Z']` and I would like to study how the `X` and `Y` influence the distribution of `Z`. For that, I wanted to use the nonparametric regressor of nadaraya watson. In statsmodels there is a class called KernelReg that implement it.

While I am able to successfully run the code for a 1-dimensional regression (`Z` on `X` and `Z` on `Y`),  I struggle to run it for the 2-dimensional regression.

My code is as follows: `XYZ` is my dataframe

```
xv = XYZ['X'].values; yv = XYZ['Y'].values; zv = XYZ['Z'].values

from statsmodels.nonparametric.kernel_regression import KernelReg
ksrmv = KernelReg(endog=zv, exog= [xv, yv], var_type='c')
```

The error I get is `cannot reshape array of size 3171442 into shape (2,1)`

```
xv.shape = yv.shape = zv.shape =(1585721,)
```

I already tried different alternative of specifying the exog like

```
XYZ.loc[:, ['X', 'Y']] or XYZ.loc[:, ['X', 'Y']].values or np.concatenate([xv[:, None], yv[:, None]])
```

always the same error.

In the description of exog in statsmodels. It should be a list of independent variable(s). Each element in the list is a separate variable, I am not sure how to interpret it.

Comment: Can you provide a full working example to check. exog should (most likely) have observations in rows, e.g. use `np.column_stack([xv, yv])`, var_type should most likely have 2 characters for the types of the exog.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the variable type needs to be given for each independent variable in the same string (i.e., in the `var_type` argument). If both variables are continuous, the code in your case would be:

```
ksrmv = KernelReg(endog=zv, exog= [xv, yv], var_type='cc')
```